# How to map DB in ListView (parking mode)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DB with the table "parking" with the 'number' and 'letter' like "1A,2A,..,3A,..,10L" (10X10) and the value if it is busy or not.

I want to map this table in a listview/gridview of a 10x10, with green box if the box is empty or red if it's full. Example: https://www.informaticanelreale.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/e-2-768x409.png

Comment: What have you tried? What is the specific problem you are trying to solve? This is a rather broad question.

Comment: I have tried to make a question.. I dont know how to map it. 
any advice is welcome :)